# How to count number of tabs in each line using shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to write a script to count the number of tabs in each line of a file and print the output to a text file (e.g., output.txt).

How do I do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
awk '{print gsub(/\t/,"")}' inputfile > output.txt
```

Comment: There needs to be a space before "inputfile"

Answer (score 13):

If you treat `\t` as the field delimiter, there will be one fewer `\t` than fields on each line:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ print NF-1 }' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I prefer this answer over the accepted use of `gsub` because it extends more easily to selecting rows based on the number of tabs. For example: `awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { if ( NF-1 != 27) print NR, NF, $0; }'` prints the line number and tab count for each line without exactly 27 tabs, followed by the offending line itself.

Comment: I prefer it because `gsub` is just doing unnecessary work after ignoring `awk`'s initial field splitting. :)

Comment: @icio You answered my broader question as well!

Answer (score 2):

```
sed 's/[^\t]//g' input.txt | awk '{ print length }' > output.txt
```

Based on [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/18742/11912).

Answer (score 2):

This will give the total number of tabs in file:

```
od -c infile | grep -o "\t" | wc -l > output.txt
```

This will give you number of tabs line by line:

```
awk '{print gsub(/\t/,"")}' infile > output.txt
```